# Traceroute failed, how to resolve?

Tags: domain-name-system, gentoo

`wget` works fine with speedtest.net, but `traceroute` does not.  How to resolve this?

```
    traceroute to www.speedtest.net (69.17.117.207), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
    ...
    4  tge11-3.fr4.dal.llnw.net (69.164.4.5)  0.000 ms  0.000 ms  0.000 ms
    5  * * *
    6  ge-0-0-2.cr2.sea1.speakeasy.net (69.17.87.17)  50.000 ms  50.000 ms  50.000 ms
    7  252.ge-1-3-0.sr2.sea5.speakeasy.net (69.17.82.62)  50.000 ms 251.ge-1-3-0.sr1.sea5.speakeasy.net (69.17.82.58)  60.000 ms  60.000 ms
    8  * * *
    9  * * *
    10  * * *
    11  * * *
    12  * * *
    13  * * *
    14  * * *
    15  * * *
    16  * * *
    17  * * *
    18  * * *
    19  * * *
    20  * * *
    21  * * *
    22  * * *
    23  * * *
    24  * * *
    25  * * *
    26  * * *
    27  * * *
    28  * * *
    29  * * *
    30  * * *
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are different versions of traceroute - some depend on icmp echos, other on udp. if for some reason your firewall/operator blocks this sort of traffic - you're out of luck.

try [mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/), or [tcptraceroute](http://michael.toren.net/code/tcptraceroute/).

also - do not expect that every end-node will respond to your requests or every router in the core will bother to send you back icmp 'time exceeded in-transit'.

Comment: Yup, normally traceroutes use ICMP traffic, however plenty of providers and admins block this. In which case you can probably use a tcp traceroute (as tcp is working since wget is working).